# Do you know any performant CMS with file based configuration?

Tags: content-management-system

I've been looking for an alternative to Drupal for a while now, mainly because I dislike the way Drupal stores all configuration in the database, thus making team development and deployment a real struggle (I'm aware that configuration management is one of the improvements coming up with Drupal 8 and I've been fighting with Features and Strongarm). The other issue I'm having with Drupal is its high memory footprint and the bazillion of database queries it does with every page call. I'm not asking for Drupal support, this is just to clarify what I'm looking for when searching alternatives.

So far I've only found two promising systems that handle configuration right:

- [Locomotive CMS](http://locomotivecms.com/) (built with Ruby on Rails)
- [Bolt CMS](http://bolt.cm) (built with PHP on top of Silex and Symfony)

Is anybody aware of other CMSes that offer a versionable, file-based configuration and therefore painless collaboration and deployment? I couldn't find any CMS round-up that looks at things from this point of view.